# hoverClass not working on draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, marionette

I have a marionette CompositeView with an onRender method:

```
onRender: function () { 
    this.$el.droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
        MyApp.vent.trigger("add:products");
    });
}
```

The css style is defined as:

```
.ui-state-hover {
    background: green !important;
}
```

The droppable element should turn green when the selection is dragged over that element. This is not happening in my application.

I do have a Fiddle where this works but don't know why it's not working in my application.

http://jsfiddle.net/netroworx/KZX7z/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
$(this).ready(function(){
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

in the first line since `$(this)` in `jsFiddle` refer to `$(document)` but maybe not in your application.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was untidy. Have fixed the fiddle. The application actually uses regions to add the view to the page via code in an app initializer called from within a RequireJS block.